# Unable to deploy to Artifactory from Maven: http error code 403

Tags: maven, artifactory

I suspect this is something simple, but I am unable to deploy any projects to a remote Artifactory repository from the Maven command line or from Eclipse. I can deploy successfully using the Artifactory web UI, but when I specify the same user account ('admin') in my Maven settings.xml file, it fails with "Error code 403, Forbidden". I am using the open source version of Artifactory, version 5.11.0. The "Password Encryption Policy" setting is "Required".

Here is the server snippet from the `~/.m2/settings.xml` file:

```
<server>
  <id>dmrepo</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>encrypted password obtained from the Artifactory UI</password>
</server>
```

and here is the deployment section of the project's `pom.xml` file:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>dmrepo</id>
        <name>myrepo-releases</name>
        <url>http://server:port/libs-release-local</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

If I re-run `mvn` with the `-e` parameter, the last error in the stack trace is:

> Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to: http://server:port/libs-release-local/path/to/jar/jarFile-version.jar, ReasonPhrase: Forbidden.

When I look in the Artifactory and Tomcat log files, I see absolutely nothing being logged during the failed deploy attempt, which makes me wonder if the request is even reaching that server, but the error code 403 is an active "you can't do that" response coming from *somewhere*, not a generic "can't reach that URL" error. Also, I can access that same host & port combination using a browser from the same machine, so I don't think this can be a firewall issue.

I have reviewed the other similar questions, but none of them seem to address this specific situation. The JFrog user guide suggests checking the include & exclude filters on the repository, but the include is set to `**/*` and the exclude is blank, which seems right to me. The other suggestion in the user guide is that 'permissions' might be the issue, but it is silent on which permissions or how to check and change them.

**Update**
Updated with (lightly redacted) output of `curl` command requested by @Ariel:

```
curl -i -vvv -u 'admin:<password>' -T <filename.jar> <hostname>:<port>/<repo_name>/<package>/<version>/<filename>
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Trying <IP_address>...
* TCP_NODELAY set 
* Connected to <hostname> (<IP_address>) port <port> (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> PUT /<repo_name>/<package>/<version>/<filename> HTTP/1.1
> Host: <hostname>:<port>
> Authorization: Basic <Base64_encoded admin:password>
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 14364
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

} [14364 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en
Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 983
Content-Length: 983
< Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2018 00:26:15 GMT
Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2018 00:26:15 GMT
< Connection: close
Connection: close

< 
{ [983 bytes data]
100 15347  100   983  100 14364   6380  93227 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 93272
* Closing connection 0
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Description</b> The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.23</h3></body></html>
```

Comment: Can you try to access artifactory first from command line without encryption and if this works than with encryption...furthermore have you correctly configured `settings-security.xml`...? Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: What do you see in the 'request.log' in Artifactory? This should also give you some information.

Comment: Also, can you try deploying the same file using curl command and see if that is working? Just to try and narrow down the issue. use 'curl -u admin:password -T filename http://server:port/libs-release-local/path/to/jar/jarFile-version.jar'

Replace the username and password, path and file name... :)

Comment: @Ariel & @khmarbaise: thanks for the suggestions. Using curl also gives the 403 error code, and that uses the unencrypted password. There's nothing at all in the `request.log` file. Where is the `settings-security.xml` file? I don't recognize that file name.

Comment: @DaveMulligan Please run the curl again and add the following flags: -i -vvv Please add the output of the curl command to this thread.

Comment: @Ariel Added to body of question so that I could format it. Thanks.

Comment: Try changing protocol prefix to `https`. If memory serves, that was the reason in my case some time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to trying HTTPS instead of HTTP, also double check the URL. By the CURL output, it seems that you are not reaching Artifactory. Your request is being stopped at the Tomcat level, that usually means that your URL for Artifactory is incorrect. Can you try: http://server:port/**artifactory**/libs-release-local/ and see if this works?

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. Shame that the UI doesn't give the correct URL when it shows you the deployment settings. Now I just have to figure out why the encrypted password isn't working...

Comment: what do you mean the UI didn't give you the right URL? Where did you copied it from? 
Do you have "base URL" configured in the "Admin --> configuration" page?

Comment: For me, https > http and ok.

Answer (score 0):

Also, artifactory might return 403 error if you're trying to deploy artifact with the already exists version